# Romaine lettuce has multiple heads really close; should I separate before planting?

Tags: lettuce

I just bought this romaine plant. It has about 5 heads really close together. Do I have to untangle them and plant them separately? Or do I leave them be? I was going to put them in a bigger box, 8x6in, but do I need something bigger because it's more than one?

[image: lettuce]

[image: lettuce]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can separate in multiple potted plants. If you wish so, you can leave them as they are, fertilizing them often when needed. It doesn't matter what you do, it's going to bolt anyway sooner or later. Separating them and leaving them to grow individually will drain less nutrients as each plant will have ample nutrients from soil as well as more room for roots to grow. Also, by the look of it, a majority of your lettuces are way past its preferred tenderness, they will probably taste bitter or unappealing (i.e. bolting). So harvest the most tender ones and leave the older ones to go to flower. That way you'll have 100s of seeds to regrow them the upcoming season.

Comment: Agree with the separation, but I disagree with the statement that they are past the preferred maturity. Those are not much bigger than seedlings, they have a lot of growing ahead until maturity.

Comment: @Stephie They are ofcourse, young seedlings but they won't have that tenderness and will be slightly (if not very at all) bitter taste. Owing to the intense chlorophyll it accumulated over it's lifetime. Except for the 2 plants in middle. It's much like the difference within a  green and white asparagus, albeit them coming from  the same plant.

Answer (score 0):

Start cutting the leaves just above the base about an inch and enjoy your lettuce while it's still at this stage of growth, if you still have season left they will grow again into new leaves to eat.